# When creating a public GitHub repo, what's the best way to deal with 3rd party libs?

Tags: github, repository

Should I include 3rd party libs in my public repo, or just add them as a requirement in a readme?

Comment: Question: what language+build system do you use ? Just curious because repository based build solutions (for java, maven is very popular, but i see it as a broader, not tight to a language, concept)

Comment: I'm working on a couple of web projects, so it's all xhtml/css/javascript/php/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a library stored in `git` and you are tracking an unstable or development tree? Use `git submodule`.

If the library is not stored in git, but you are tracking an unstable tool, write a small shell script to automate your life of fetching the required source.

Is it a released library? Require the user to provide it.